# authenticating to run a function within .net form application

Tags: c#, .net, smartcard, remedy

I was hoping someone could clear up some confusion I have with using domain credentials to run a function. We use remedy for our ticket system, which normally uses an SSO library to authenticate using fat client and web brower authentication on the web version. I would like to be able to use the remedy .net API which uses domain credentials to login.

My main issue is that we are not able to type our passwords because of Group policy, so how do I pass my credentials to the remedy API?

If possible I would like to use the credentials of the person logged on. If it meant using a smartcard that would not be an issue, as long as I could use the credentials inside the remedy API.

Example:

```
BMC.ARSystem.Server arserver = new BMC.ARSystem.Server();
arserver.Login("servername", "username", "password", "");
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you need another layer of authentication.  To login onto the PC, windows already used the Group Policy Authentication.  So why do another authentication?  You could use Network.Credentials but that simply get the credentials from the User Account on the PC.

Comment: How would I use that authentication with the remedy API to log in?. I am getting authentication error when I don't supply user/pass.

Comment: I don't think it needs the windows(group policy) password.  It looks like the username/password is used to create a temporary token.  So any password can be used.  See : https://docs.bmc.com/docs/display/public/ars9000/Login+information#Logininformation-tokenTocreatethetoken

Comment: Hmm, not sure what  I am doing wrong,
 arserver.Login("servername", Environment.UserName,"myusername","blah");
            Error(623): Authentication failed;

Comment: jdweng, I am wondering if that is for the c# .net or just for web based java?

Comment: It shouldn't make a different if it is java or c# if it is using a http post.  I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to get detailed error message.  It looks like the API is just creating a HTTP Request.  I suspect one of three things 1) A certificate is needed 2) A cookie issue.  Maybe need to delete cookies from IE history 3) A missing header setting in the http header.  The API constructor may have optional parameters that you are not setting.  See : https://docs.bmc.com/docs/display/public/ars9000/Operations+on+entry+objects

Comment: I just notice the login is using http1.1 which may be an issue.  See : https://docs.bmc.com/docs/display/public/ars9000/Login+information Then Net library doesn't work with 1.1 (only 1.0).  It shouldn't make a difference.  but I'm wondering what the default version is in the Http Request.  Does it match the url for the login.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151518/discussion-between-user2190928-and-jdweng).